# Vector field derived from Group action on smooth manifolds

Tags: lie-groups, group-actions, vector-fields

It is known that given a smooth action $G$ on $M$,
$$G\times M\to M$$
one can
associate to each element of $v\in T_eG$ a vector field on $X\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$. I want to see a less obvious and concrete example and know that is this fact just about Lie groups of positive dimension or it is meaningful for discrete groups action too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing goes wrong in the case of a discrete (i.e. $0$-dimensional) Lie group; it's just a rather trivial case: If $G$ is a discrete group, then the tangent space is a singleton $T_eG=\{0\}$, and $0\in T_eG$ corresponds to the zero vector field $0\in\mathfrak{X}M$.

Comment: How to see that $0\in T_eG$ corresponds to the zero vector field $0\in\mathfrak{X}M$?

Comment: Up to some sign conventions depending on if $\theta$ is a left or right action, the vector field $\hat{V}\in\mathfrak{X}M$ corresponding to $V\in\mathfrak{g}$ is defined by$$\hat{V}(p)=\frac{d}{dt}\theta_{\exp(tV)}(p)|_{t=0}$$ $0\in\mathfrak{g}$ generates the constant flow $\theta_{\exp(t0)}(p)=\theta_ep,=p$ whose derivative is $0\in\mathfrak{X}M$.